# Can created creatures awaken?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

In Mage The Ascension it is possible for technocrats to create androids via a mix of life and mind as per the rote

> AI (Artificial Intelligence):
> With this rote, a Technomage can create a full
> artificial intelligence. It can live in a computer, be
> transferred to the Digital Web or, with Life, given a
> living body.

What I want to ask is that is it possible for a being created this way to awaken and become a mage itself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### It's happened before.

In the Sons of Ether tradition book, there's a NPC who's an analog to Frankenstein's Monster — Victor, by name — who is both a created being and an Awakened mage.

Comment: Also, there is a few character ideas in Technocracy books. One was a pre-made character, IIRC. And from what I remember, there was a clone who Awakened, and there was some (constructed) cyborg. I can't remember which books - I suspect it's the Guide to the Technocracy and the (pre-M20) Convention books.